# Find missing records in many-to-many junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a many-to-many junction table that joins 2 tables:

table1

```
table1_id 
-----------
1
2
3
```

table2

```
table2_id
------------
A
B
C
```

join_table

```
table1_id   |   table2_id
------------|--------------
1           |  A
1           |  B
1           |  C
2           |  A
2           |  C
3           |  B
```

How can I write a single query to find out what records are missing from the join table, since I want all combinations accounted for. Basically, I want a query that returns these missing records:

```
table1_id   |   table2_id
---------------------------
2           |  B
3           |  A
3           |  C
```

I feel like this should be simple but I haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do a `CROSS JOIN` to get all possible combinations. Then use `EXCEPT` to remove the existing combinations.

```
select t1.table1_id, t2.table2_id
from t1 cross join t2
except
select table1_id, table2_id from join_table
```

Comment: all? Could this be an error from being used to many union alls?

Comment: No `ALL` according to the [syntax in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax) (And not a documentation bug - "The 'ALL' version of the EXCEPT operator is not supported." error if you try to use it)

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, perhaps an old habit... Shouldn't matter here I suppose, since there are no duplicate rows.

Comment: it's not just redundunt; it won't work...as damien notes

Comment: Now edited. (Didn't know SQL Server doesn't support EXCEPT ALL...)